# is it possible to use didUpdateToLocation in ios8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

Is it possible to use

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:
(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

in ios8.

it is deprecated in ios8. However i used the same to get the updated location.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can check below snippet.

> #define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
>
> //In ViewDidLoad
>
> if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {    [self.locationManager
> requestAlwaysAuthorization]; }
>
> [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

And do changes in info.plist file as you can in the image.

[image]

Comment: even i did the same. but my problem is: speed is keep increasing even device is not in running.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the deprecated methods but you should use :

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`

To calcule the speed :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *loc = locations.lastObject;
    double speed = loc.speed;
    NSLog(@"%f", speed);
}
```

Comment: but speed is keep increasing even if device not running

Comment: can you tell me how to calculate speed

Comment: I tested in device. speed is giving in negative.